# When extension of a maximal ideal is maximal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, flatness, local-rings

Let $R \subseteq S$ be two commutative rings satisfying the following conditions:

**(1)** $R$ and $S$ are $\mathbb{C}$-algebras.

**(2)** $R$ and $S$ are integral domains. Denote their fields of fractions by $Q(R)$ and $Q(S)$.

**(3)** $S=R[w]$, for some $w \in S$, namely, $R \subseteq S$ is simple.

**(4)** $\dim(R)=\dim(S) < \infty$, where $\dim$ is the Krull dimension.

**(5)** $R$ and $S$ are local rings, with $m_RS=m_S$, where $m_R$ is the maximal ideal of $R$, $m_S$ is the maximal ideal of $S$, and $m_RS$ is the ideal generated by $m_R$ in $S$, namely, $m_R$ extended to $S$.

**(6)** $R \subseteq S$ is flat.

**(7)** $R \subseteq S$ is algebraic, not integral.

> **Claim:** $R=S$.
>
> **Question:** Could one prove or find a counterexample to the above claim?

**Remark:** Without condition **(7)**, the following is a counterexample to the claim:
$R=\mathbb{C}[x(x-1),y]_{(x(x-1),y)}$, $S=\mathbb{C}[x,y]_{(x,y)}$, $m_R=x(x-1)R+yR$, $m_S=xS+yS$.

**Motivation:** Theorem 2 in [Richman's paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1965-016-04/S0002-9939-1965-0181653-1/S0002-9939-1965-0181653-1.pdf) deals with $R \subseteq S$ having the same fields of fractions. If one insists, I could have assumed flatness and other conditions on non-local domains $R \subseteq S$, $m$ maximal in $R$, $n$ maximal in $S$ with $m=R \cap n$, $mR_m S_n=nS_n$, wishing to conclude that $R_m=S_n$.

The following two questions are relevant: [a](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4092716/definition-of-homomorphism-of-local-rings/4093922#4093922) and [b](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1814903/localization-of-a-local-ring/1814925).
Also asked in [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/389850/certain-r-subseteq-s-with-m-maximal-in-r-and-me-maximal-in-s).

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please, the one who wants to close my question, could you explain why?

Comment: I did not vote to close, but I can guess about the reasoning.  The question you are asking is at the end (it takes a while to understand what it is that you want to know), and you seem to be asking at least two questions.  In general, it is best to ask narrow, focused questions.

Comment: @XanderHenderson, thank you for your comment, for trying to help. I will try to improve it later.

Comment: I'm confused about (2). Obviously if $R=S$, then $Q(R) = Q(S)$, so if (2) holds $R \neq S$ trivially.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson, thank you very much for your comment! You are right, so I should delete $Q(R)=Q(S)$.